# How can I add break before each character '' - ''?

Tags: php, character, break

I have some text from database like this:
- cauko2, - kldsflkajflad alkdjfalkj l lkdj la kdsjf kdjfkldjfk lkdjf lakj lkjldjf lkljlfj ldjlkkjlajlsfjlajfl lkadjk lkdj lkfkdjfkdjfk, - skajf lkja kldjfaklj, - lkasjdfkjdkfj alkdf lksdjflksdjflakjdlk ladjklfjslkdjf alkdjflkdj fkldjf - lkdjflkadjflajl,

and I need to insert break 
 before each " - " character.
Could you please help me?
I need it in PHP. 
Thanks

Comment: break as `</br>` or as line break?

Comment: you should show that you have made an attempt to do this yourself when posting on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$str = "- cauko2, - kldsfk, -asdas asd a";
echo str_replace("-", "<br />-", $str);
```

Comment: @Sonia Your welcome, you can accept the answer as correct to help other users to find the right answer as well :)